# Ubuntu 19.04 Shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on my Lenovo ThinkCentre-M73 Tiny.

All works very well and im happy, away from that when i tap shutdown the machine is just restarting.

I also tried the terminal way to shut it down but the same thing is happening.

So i basically need to hold on/off button to turn it off everytime.

Any solutions out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have same Lenovo and the same problem. Disabling wake on LAN in the BIOS works in my case.

Comment: I don't have a Lenovo so I can't say as to if this is a good answer or not but it seems like it would be a good solution.  I would be good if you can expand your answer to tell the OP the steps needed to do this.  Not all users know how to navigate the bios of their computer.